# Multiple textbox value addition using single button click event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 15 text boxes and 1 button in my Windows application.

What I want to do is to add the value of 15 text box using single button click event. Is it possible??

I tried to declare an array and then for loop on array, but it shows an error "cannot convert to int"

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)      
{
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    while (i <= r15c5)
    {
        j = j + i;
        j--;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Soner Gönül its R2D2's successor

Comment: @Uzi first of all, could you be more specific as to what type of windows application? Asp.net(because you flagged it), or Win Forms, or WPF ?

Comment: There are many ways to solve this. Cannot convert to int, suggests the content of you textbox wasn't an int. check for that and your code (whatever it is..) will probably work. PS j is very very bad name for total...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on .Net framework 3.5 or above, you can use Linq, and do it in one line:

first, you import:

```
using System.Linq;
```

and then:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Sum(t => Int32.Parse(t.Text)).ToString());
}
```

Explanation:

```
//selects all text boxes in your form
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()

//gets the sum of all the textboxes according to the selector inside the .Sum() function
.Sum(t => Int32.Parse(t.Text))

//a Lambda expression to select the texts of the text boxes, and parse them as integers
t => Int32.Parse(t.Text)]
```

- more about lambda expressions can be found [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure what you meant there, but this piece of code creates an array, adding 2 textboxes (You can add as many textboxes as you like) and sums their values:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox[] texts = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2 };
    int sum = 0;

    foreach (TextBox textBox in texts)
        sum += int.Parse(textBox.Text);

}
```

The int.Parse gets an int from the text string